# Can Thevenin voltage ever be negative?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, electrical-engineering

So in context of Thevenin's and Norton's theorem, can Thevenin voltage $V_{th}$, as in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thevenin_theorem, ever be negative? I know that $R_{th}$ can be negative, but never thought of $V_{th}$ one until now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  It depends on how you define the direction of positive voltage in your equivalent voltage source.   In other words, if you switch the positions of the "+" and "-" on a typical diagram, the sign of the voltage will switch.